# How to do arithmetic operations using parenthesis

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to calculate the minimum distance between two points in (longitude / latitude) in a database.

In SQLite I can write (example):

```sql
SELECT POWER(latitude-40,2) + POWER(longitude-32,2) * 0.5
FROM example_table
```

(0.5 is a correction factor for better approximation)

When I try to do the same thing in SQLAlchemy:

```
db.query((models.example_table.latitude - 40) * (models.example_table.latitude - 40) + (models.example_table.longitude - 32) * (models.example_table.longitude - 32) * 0.5).first()
```

then the produced SQL is wrong as it uses '||' instead of '+':

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT (example_table.latitude - ?) * (example_table.latitude - ?) || (example_table.longitude - ?) * (example_table.longitude - ?) * ? AS anon_1
FROM example_table
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00078s] (43, 43, 32, 32, 0.5, 1, 0)
(-56.749055346000006,)
```

and of course the result is also wrong.

How can I fix this?

Comment: which database do you use? and what are the datatypes for the `latitude` and `longitude` columns?

Comment: I am using SQLite. longitute, latitude are VARCHARs (Column(String, nullable=False))

Comment: `||` is string concatenation, which stems from your choice of type for the columns. While SQLite happily converts them to numbers for arithmetic, not all DBMS do. Cast them explicitly to get the correct expression.

Comment: Yep!! That was it! @IljaEverilä . I casted it as numeric like this: `db.query((cast(models.example_table.latitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 43) * 
 (cast(models.example_table.latitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 43) + 
 (cast(models.example_table.longitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 32) * 
 (cast(models.example_table.longitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 32) * 
 .5)` and it did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the parenthesis works out of the box.

In my case the problem was that the 2 parameters (longitude, latitude) were modelled as String(s) (VARCHARs). Then, DBMS was trying then to concatenate strings and not numbers.

The solution was to cast the columns as numbers like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, Numeric

db.query(
(cast(models.example_table.latitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 43) *
(cast(models.example_table.latitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 43) +
(cast(models.example_table.longitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 32) *  
(cast(models.example_table.longitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 32) * 
.5)
```

Many thanks to the people in the comments.

Comment: You can also use the [POWER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#pow) function: `db.query(func.power(cast(model.example_table.latitude, Numeric(10, 8)) - 43), 2) + ...)`

Comment: That would be a beauty. SQLite supports it but i cannot find the "func.power" is sql alchemy ORM. I get: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: power`. Do I need to import something special?

Comment: Well, the link i provided in the first comment is that of the sqlite, so maybe this depends on the sqlite version you are using. Try `POW` instead.